# Proof that Continuity Implies $\epsilon$-$\delta$ Criterion

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, continuity, epsilon-delta

> (1) **$\epsilon$-$\delta$ Criterion**: For each $\epsilon > 0$, there is a $\delta > 0$ such that, for all $x$ in $\text{Dom}(f)$, $|x - c| \leq \delta \implies |f(x) - f(c)| \leq \epsilon$.

In this book's proof that continuity implies the above criterion, we have:

> ... we give a contrapositive proof. That is, assume there exists an $\epsilon > 0$ so that there is no $\delta$ so that (1) holds. We'll show that $f$ is not contnuous at $c$. Let $\delta_n = \frac{1}{n}$. **Since (1) does not hold, there is an $x_n \in \text{Dom}(f)$ satisfying $$|x_n - c| \leq \delta_n$$ such that $$|f(x_n) - f(c)| > \epsilon$$**

I bolded the statement I'm having an issue with: Why can we make this statement? We know that, for *some* $\epsilon$, (1) does not hold, but where does that allow us to assume a particular $\delta_n$? Where were we able to assume that that $|x_n - c| \leq \delta_n$ for some $x_n$?

I know it may seem like somewhat of a trivial question, but I do not see where this assumption is validated.

Comment: Look at the numbers $1, 1/2, 1/3, 1/4, \ldots$, which are all the possible values of $\delta_n$. If the bolded statement were false, meaning for any $\delta_n$ you choose there is no $x_n \in \text{Dom}(f)$ satisfying
$$|x_n - c| \leq \delta_n$$ 
such that 
$$|f(x_n) - f(c)| < \varepsilon,$$
then your function would have to be continuous, because the $\delta_n$ become arbitrarily small, so for any $\varepsilon$ you can find a $\delta_n < \varepsilon$.

Comment: @nsanger This is my understanding: If there is no $x_n$ such that $|x_n-c| \leq \delta_n$ such that $|f(x_n) - f(c)| < \epsilon$, then $x_n \rightarrow c \implies f(x_n) \rightarrow f(c)$ (because there are no convergent $x_n$, so the implication still holds), which is just the definition of continuity. Is this correct? If it is, where is $|f(x_n) - f(c)| < \epsilon$ but $|x_n - c| \geq \delta_n$ ruled out?